# Merge patch json array items?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following json array...

```
[
{ "class":"Identity", "id":5, "type":6 },
{ "class":"Combat", "damage":10.0 },
.
.
.
]
```

I want to update the json object where `'class'='Identity'` and add a few more values to it like `{ 'x':5 }` or something similar. So a `JSON_MERGE_PATCH`.

But as far as i know that merge patch does only accept a json as an input... not a path to an json object.

So how do we add/merge patch an json object in an array ?

Comment: Use `JSON_EXTRACT()` to get the nested object, call `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()` on that, and then merge that result into the array.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks ! But how do i merge the result into the array ? By using a merge_patch or merge_preserve it would break because it can not handle this case proberly.

Comment: I suppose you have to use `JSON_REPLACE()` and just overwrite the whole object with a new object you create by adding the values to the old object. Keep at it! Eventually you'll [implement a whole data-management system on top of SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). :-)